# F# on Monodevelop: compiler doesn't understand valid Linux file path

Tags: linux, f#, monodevelop

I am new to F#. I get the following error when I attempt to build my F# project in Monodevelop:

> /home/greenrd/git/hello/hello: Error FS0229: Error opening binary file
>   '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/../../../../../usr/lib/mono/gac/kde-dotnet/4.1.0.0_*194a23ba31c08164/kde-dotnet.dll':
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   "usr/lib/mono/gac/kde-dotnet/4.1.0.0*_194a23ba31c08164/kde-dotnet.dll".
>   (FS0229) (hello)

I don't think this is due to the 260 character file path limit in .NET, for the simple reason that the file path is only 102 characters. What could be the problem? `file` says:

> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/../../../../../usr/lib/mono/gac/kde-dotnet/4.1.0.0__194a23ba31c08164/kde-dotnet.dll:
>   PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS
>   Windows

I don't even know where this filename comes from, I didn't enter such a strange filename anywhere. All I did was add the KDE C# bindings as a reference to the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the compiler when there are more `..` than required - it looks like in this case the compiler drops the leading slash.

Changing the reference to

```
/usr/lib/mono/gac/kde-dotnet/4.1.0.0__194a23ba31c08164/kde-dotnet.dll
```

works just fine.

I am trying to chase this error up.  Hopefully I will have a compiler patch today or tomorrow.

So after chasing a whole stack of functions in the compiler, it turns out this is actually a mono bug.  This simplest way to reproduce it is

```
new FileStream("/../bin/bash",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);;
```

which should work, but doesn't.

Reported to mono: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17083

**EDIT:**  This is apparently fixed in the latest mono - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17083

Comment: This is the kind of bug I'm surprised hasn't been found before. A lot of people use Mono...